# Reading Binary file chunk by chunk and loading in bitset

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, bitset

Suppose I have a 1 GB binary file. I also have a function which take a 128 bit bitset perform some operation and and produce a 128 bit bitset. Now iteratively read 128 bit chunk from the file; process it and write the results in a binary file. I didn't get good resource on how to read 128 bit chunk read and load.I am new to C++.
Any help or resource giving is highly appreciated.

Comment: It may be as simple as opening up a [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and calling [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to suck 128 bits directly from the file into the bitset, but you have provided too little information for a concrete answer. The solution is likely to be something with `ifstream` and `read`, so start your research there.

Comment: Based on your question on [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/82120/36960), could it be said that you have a concrete application that you want to implement?

Comment: @DannyNiu yes actually I am writing an application which does performance comparison of various encryption algorithms based on their encryption speed.

Comment: @Radium, Awesome, in which case I believe you might want to exclude disk IO delays from your experiments. I'd suggest allocate 1MiB of memory buffer (e.g. `malloc` in C, in C++ I think it should be `new`) and fill it with random data, and use that as your test data.